# loading model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

I am having an error that is "Unable to locate the model you have specified: Settings"
Here is my Settings model and my file name is also settings. Its working good in localhost but after uploading it in my server its showing the error. How can i solve this : web link: http://layakdesign.co.nf/

error showing : "Unable to locate the model you have specified: Settings"

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Settings extends CI_Model
{
         public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_settings($code)
    {
        CI::db()->where('code', $code);
        $result = CI::db()->get('settings');

        $return = [];
        foreach($result->result() as $results)
        {
            $return[$results->setting_key]  = $results->setting;
        }
        return $return; 
    }

    /*
    settings should be an array
    array('setting_key'=>'setting')
    $code is the item that is calling it
    ex. any shipping settings have the code "shipping"
    */
    public function save_settings($code, $values)
    {
        //get the settings first, this way, we can know if we need to update or insert settings
        //we're going to create an array of keys for the requested code
        $settings   = $this->get_settings($code);

        //loop through the settings and add each one as a new row
        foreach($values as $key=>$value)
        {
            //if the key currently exists, update the setting
            if(array_key_exists($key, $settings))
            {
                $update = array('setting'=>$value);
                CI::db()->where('code', $code);
                CI::db()->where('setting_key',$key);
                CI::db()->update('settings', $update);
            }
            //if the key does not exist, add it
            else
            {
                $insert = array('code'=>$code, 'setting_key'=>$key, 'setting'=>$value);
                CI::db()->insert('settings', $insert);
            }
        }
    }

    //delete any settings having to do with this particular code
    public function delete_settings($code)
    {
        CI::db()->where('code', $code);
        CI::db()->delete('settings');
    }

    //this deletes a specific setting
    public function delete_setting($code, $setting_key)
    {
        CI::db()->where('code', $code);
        CI::db()->where('setting_key', $setting_key);
        CI::db()->delete('settings');
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did : "Unable to locate the model you have specified: Settings"

Comment: your are not extending modal class

Comment: updated my code but still same error.

Comment: link of my website : http://layakdesign.co.nf/

Comment: which codeigniter version you are using ?

Comment: i am using version 3.0.0

Comment: please you can post how to load model in Controller.

Comment: [Answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33990768/3638151) worked for me without any file editing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create model following way.

**Settings_model.php**

http://layakdesign.co.nf//application/models/settings_model.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Settings_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    ...

}
?>
```

Load your model in Specific Controller file.

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Setting extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('settings_model');
        }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: thanx for the solution...:)

Answer (score 0):

It's issue of class name and filename, make small letter to class name as well filename

```
class settings extends CI_Model
{
...
}
```

and file name too settings.php

Answer (score 0):

If your model file name settings.php
than to write code like

```
$this->load->model('settings');
```

whatever your file name must be decalre same name in the model function.